# Openni for groovy version

Tags: ros, openni, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

My question is: for groovy version of ROS on linux which openni packages will give full openni installation?

I have openni_launch. Should I also install openni_kinect, openni_camera, etc.?

It seems that different packages are needed for different versions and I don't want to ruin something, since I'm very unsure linux user.

I tried to understand this through tutorials, but seem to have problems here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66460/openni-for-groovy-version/) by [Natti](https://answers.ros.org/users/5133/natti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just install the openni_launch and the openni_camera

---

Originally posted by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) with karma: 200 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1